# Python3.5 Xlib error anyone met the same?

Tags: python-3.5, xlib, display, pyautogui

I am trying to install pyautogui. And it have some error shown as below:

```
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    display = Display()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 160, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'No protocol specified\n'
```

then I googled and found some experts had found some bugs:

https://github.com/LiuLang/python3-xlib/issues/6
https://github.com/LiuLang/python3-xlib/issues/7

so they solved it by change the code of xauth.py in Xlib. 
While when I followed it, it raised another error shown as below:

```
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    display = Display()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 92, in __init__
    name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 101, in get_auth
    return mod.get_auth(sock, dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 124, in new_get_auth
    return au.get_best_auth(family, addr, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 112, in get_best_auth
    address = address.encode()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

have you ever met the similar issue? or it is because of my system have something wrong?

(edited later)

I just tried to do everything in python2.7.12 I had met the below error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    display = Display()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 92, in __init__
    name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 101, in get_auth
    return mod.get_auth(sock, dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 121, in new_get_auth
    au = xauth.Xauthority()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Xlib/xauth.py", line 47, in __init__
    raise error.XauthError('~/.Xauthority: %s' % err)
XauthError: ~/.Xauthority: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rnie/.Xauthority'
```

Have you met this problem? the .Xauthority should be under my user home directory by default, right? I can not find it by checking "cat ~/.Xauthority". It says no such a file:(

Comment: I would remove this line 112 and see what happens. Seems that the port from python 2 is not very polished :)

Comment: When I removed the line 112, it will go back to the original error. seems some conflicts here.

Comment: shot in the dark: try this in line 112: `address = address.decode("ascii")`

Comment: it will go back to the original error.

Comment: Jean_Francois,  I have gave up the python3.5 and try to solve the problem in old-fashion python2.7. I got some other problem on Xauthority error as shown above. I googled and fail to find solution. I checked my fedora25/24 in virtual box. I can never find any such a file named .Xauthority.   also my env $XAUTHORITY is " "(not set). I used the xauth to try to creat, while failed by saying no such a file.... Could you bring me some light on this?